Vercel NodeJS Express Post method not working
I'm trying to deploy an api that was built on nodejs and somehow after submitting my request i see the error as below
    $ vercel dev
Vercel CLI 34.2.7
> Ready! Available at http://localhost:3000
InternalServerError: stream is not readable
    at readStream (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:178:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:109:12)
    at read (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:79:3)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:135:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at query (C:\Users\mypc\MyDrive\workspace\visualstudio\sample-vercel\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)

My index.js file is as below
const express = require('express');
const cron = require("node-cron");
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

var environment = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'components', 'env', 'environment'));
var properties = new PropertiesReader(environment);
    var routes = require('../components/controllers/routes');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../components/static')));
app.use('/sw.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../components/static/sw.js')));

routes(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || properties.get('main.app.port');
if (require.main === module) {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server ready on port '+PORT));
}


module.exports = app;

route.js file as below
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secretsession',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));

    // set the view engine to ejss
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../static/index.html'));
    });
    
    app.post('/send', function (req, res) {

                console.log("Request Received");
        });
   }

I believe the request is not even reaching to the route post /send method and failing to receive it from the browser. I even tried to post this from postman and it failed with the same error.

As we can see, it may be due to some conflict or missing in Node library - node_modules. Please see if the these posts help 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653736/nodejs-form-submission-throwing-internal-server-error-streams-not-readable. 2) https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3203#issuecomment-355137794 3)

@WeDoTheBest4You unfortunately none of the links provided works for me 1. i'm not using express-formable and 2 is not applicable in my case. Not sure if there is any 3rd link :)

Thank you for your update. Sorry, there was no third link, it was my mistake - a typo.

It worked after I have removed the below snippet from my code and built once through vercel
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

But any requests sent to my server are having an empty body. So added back the above and for some reason it started working. Strange!!!

The following information may find relevant in this context.

That means you don't have to use bodyParser.json() anymore if you are on the latest release. You can use express.json() instead.

Citation : express.json vs bodyParser.json
